# Nested returns within functions

Tags: javascript

Here is my code I would like to analyze:

```
function words(inputString) {
    var wordArray = inputString.match(/\w+/gi);
     return wordsObject(wordArray); // Why is return needed here if a return 
     // return is already in the last line of the wordsObject function below?
     // shouldn't that return the finalWordObj?

}

function wordsObject(wordArr){
    var finalWordObject = {};

    wordArr.forEach(function(item){
        item = item.toLowerCase();

        item in finalWordObject ? finalWordObject[item]++ : finalWordObject[item] = 1;
    });
    return finalWordObject;
}
```

If you look at my comments on line 3, I had to use `return wordsObject(wordArray)`.  I am wondering why I had to use return since in the function `wordsObject(wordArr)` I return the object(`finalWordObject`) it creates.  Why doesn't this `return` carry over whenever the `wordsObject` function is ran?

Comment: [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) means "return the specific value to *where* the function is called".

Comment: Think about what it would mean if returning from called functions immediately caused the caller to return.  How would you put more than one function call in a function body?

Comment: Thanks.  Just wondering why this is such a terrible question? I didn't think i phrased the question poorly even if it is basic or obvious to some. I've been working on that snippet ofcode all day trying to learn and was missing the 'return' for a while.

Comment: @HelloWorld - Probably because the question does not show any research effort. A quick search on Google will answer your question.

Comment: Does anyone have any good sources online that further explain the return statement? I am currently working with a new problem and don't understand how return is working.  I really don't get how it's working after searching and reading documentation.  If anyone knows of any good resources I would appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to a function is a request for the function to "do its thing". Functions may or may not return a value, but if they do then the value is available in the calling environment.

Calling a function without paying attention to the return value:

```
wordsObject( wordArray );
```

causes the function to run, and the return value is discarded. It's kind-of like performing a computation without assigning the result to a variable:

```
15 * 3;
```

The returned value from a function is available as a term in the expression in which it appeared:

```
var x = Math.sin( angle );
```

That's a call to a function, and the returned value is stored in the variable "x".

A `return` statement can be followed by an expression. The meaning is that the expression should be evaluated, and then the enclosing function should terminate with the value of the expression as the returned value of its invocation in its own calling context.

Thus, in order to cause a function to return the value of a call to *another* function, you need to make that function call on the right-hand side of a `return` statement:

```
return wordsObject( wordArray );
```

Some programming languages treat the last expression of a function as special, and implicitly use it as the return value. JavaScript is **not** one of those  languages.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `words()`, it returns what is returned when you call `wordsObject`.  Simply calling that function will only execute the function, giving the output.  `return` makes that function give the output of the other function.  For example:

```
function b() {
    return 1+1;
}
function a() {
    return b();
}

console.log( a() );
```

Will log `2`.